# How do I make an infinite series using an equation?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function called `cos_series` that uses values `x` and `nterms` that gives me the sum of a series, using this equation 1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4! - x^6/6! +...

This is my code so far,

```py
def cos_series(x,nterms):
    lst = []
    lst2 = []
    for i in range(nterms):
        lst+=[x**(2*i)/(math.factorial(i*2))]
    for i in range(nterms):
        lst2+=[(x**(2*i)/(math.factorial(i*2)))*-1]
    return sum(lst2[1::2] + lst[::2])

cos_series(math.pi/3,3)
```

The return value should equal 0.501796 but I'm having trouble reaching it, can anyone help?

Comment: They alternate signs, sorry about the typo

Comment: Also, is `n` supposed signify the number of terms of the form `x^p/p!`, or should `n` count the `1` term? (which would be the 0th term of the same form)

Comment: nterms should be an int that should signify the number of terms of x^p/p!. That being, if nterms = 5 it would go to the 5th iteration of x^p/p!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to make a taylor series expansion of the cosine function. If so, why would the return value of passing in `math.pi` be `0.501796` and not the `cos(pi)` which is `-1`?

Comment: How do you reckon 0.501796 should be the answer? 1 - pi^2/2! + pi^4/4! is 0.124 and if you add a term, it's -1.211

Comment: I made a few errors when copying the code over, I'm trying to take the cos of pi/3 in a Taylor series of cos(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work just fine.

Your logic works with just:

```
def cos_series(x, n):
    return sum((-1 if (i % 2) else 1) * x**(i*2) / math.factorial(i*2) for i in range(n))
```

Generating the sum of the series in one go and avoiding the computation of values you don't use.

(note that, after you changed your question, your code in fact returns `0.501796201500181` - which is the value you expected; there's no issue?)

Comment: Yes, you got it! Thank you so much. My typos made this incredibly difficult for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use math.factorial() and you don't need to store the terms in a list.  Just build the numerator and denominator as you go and add up them up.

By producing the numerator and denominator iteratively, your logic will be much easier to manage and debug:

```
def cos(x,nTerms=10):
    result      = 0
    numerator   = 1
    denominator = 1
    for even in range(2,nTerms*2+1,2):          # nTerms even numbers
        result      += numerator / denominator  # sum of terms            
        numerator   *= -x*x                     # +/- for even powers of x
        denominator *= even * (even-1)          # factorial of even numbers
    return result

print(cos(3.141592653589793/3,3)) # 0.501796201500181
```

Comment: Factorial is incredibly wasteful, especially if it doesn't use memoization.  Your solution building up the values using multiplication is the way to go.